# How to set popup scene mouse transparent in javafx

Tags: javafx

How to do that in JavaFX?
The popup shows up when the mouse enters a node. When the mouse enters the showing popup, the popup obscures the mouse from the node. Then the node fire exit event. How to make the popup ignore the mouse events?

code

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Point3D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Popup;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));

        Label labelNode = new Label("Label Node");
        labelNode.setPrefHeight(200);
        labelNode.styleProperty().set("-fx-background-color: orange");
        Popup popup = new Popup();
        popup.getScene().getRoot().setMouseTransparent(true);
        AnchorPane popContent =new AnchorPane();
        popContent.styleProperty().set("-fx-background-color: red");
        popContent.setPrefHeight(100);
        popContent.getChildren().add(new Label("Popup content"));
        popup.getContent().add(popContent);
        labelNode.setOnMouseEntered(event->{
            Point3D point3D = labelNode.localToScene(event.getX(), event.getY(), 0);
            popup.show(primaryStage, point3D.getX()-5, point3D.getY()-5);
        });

        labelNode.setOnMouseExited(event->{
            popup.hide();
        });
        root.getChildren().add(labelNode);

        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Please try moving the cursor in to "yellow" several times.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: sounds like a x-y-problem ... [mcve] please

Comment: @M.S. I have found no direct way. But my solution is to check if mouse exited  the popup && mouse exited the node to hide or keep showing it.

Answer (score -1):

Solution:
Keep two boolean nodeExited and popupExited statuses. Hide popup when both are true.

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Point3D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Popup;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {
    boolean nodeExited = false;
    boolean popupExited = false;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));


        Label labelNode = new Label("Label Node");
        labelNode.setPrefHeight(200);
        labelNode.styleProperty().set("-fx-background-color: orange");
        Popup popup = new Popup();
        popup.getScene().getRoot().setMouseTransparent(true);
        AnchorPane popContent = new AnchorPane();
        popContent.styleProperty().set("-fx-background-color: red");
        popContent.setPrefHeight(100);
        popContent.getChildren().add(new Label("Popup content"));
        popup.getContent().add(popContent);

        popup.getScene().setOnMouseEntered(event -> {
            popupExited = false;
        });

        popup.getScene().setOnMouseExited(event -> {
            popupExited = true;
            if (nodeExited)
                popup.hide();
        });

        labelNode.setOnMouseEntered(event -> {
            nodeExited = false;
            Point3D point3D = labelNode.localToScene(event.getX(), event.getY(), 0);
            popup.show(primaryStage, point3D.getX() - 5, point3D.getY() - 5);
        });

        labelNode.setOnMouseExited(event -> {
            nodeExited = true;
            if (popupExited)
                popup.hide();
        });
        root.getChildren().add(labelNode);

        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```